# php array filter out old date

Tags: php, arrays, date

I have the following array:

```
$avail = array($this->item->extraFields->RoomONEDateAvailable->value, $this->item->extraFields->RoomTWODateAvailable->value, $this->item->extraFields->RoomTHREEDateAvailable->value, $this->item->extraFields->RoomFOURDateAvailable->value, $this->item->extraFields->RoomFIVEDateAvailable->value, $this->item->extraFields->RoomSIXDateAvailable->value, $this->item->extraFields->RoomSEVENDateAvailable->value, $this->item->extraFields->RoomEIGHTDateAvailable->value, $this->item->extraFields->RoomNINEDateAvailable->value, $this->item->extraFields->RoomTENDateAvailable->value);
```

These are the actual values:

```
Array ( [0] => Thursday, 01 January 1970 [1] => Thursday, 03 September 2015 [2] => Thursday, 01 January 1970 [3] => Thursday, 01 January 1970 [4] => Thursday, 01 January 1970 [5] => Thursday, 01 January 1970 [6] => Thursday, 01 January 1970 [7] => Thursday, 01 January 1970 [8] => Thursday, 01 January 1970 [9] => Thursday, 01 January 1970 )
```

I need to remove all the 'Thursday, 01 January 1970' dates from the array, so it only contains valid dates, how can I do this please?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$avail = array_diff($avail, array('Thursday, 01 January 1970'));
```

Comment: this is a nice solution! wow, there are so many array functions in PHP - I'll never know them all.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to rebuild your array, you can remove array entries with `unset()`[[reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)].
**update:** you don't need a reference here, you can work with the corresponding array directly:

```
foreach($avail as $key => $val)
{
    if($val == "Thursday, 01, January 1970")
        unset($avail[$key]);
}

var_dump($avail);
```

this is tested and should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array_keys() functions, adding the option to search for a specific value, like this:

```
array_keys($array, "Thursday, 01 January 1970")
```

It will return an array of matching index, which you should unset from the original array.